# How can I find the pageview count of all articles in a Wikipedia category?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

I'm trying to find the most popular pages in the [logos requested category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_requested_logos) and add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [Massviews Analysis tool](https://tools.wmflabs.org/massviews/) by wmflabs.

It allows you to lookup any category and see the pageviews for all articles in that category.